# How to use Apache commons-math RealVector sparse iterators?

Tags: apache, math, matrix, apache-commons-math

I would like to iterate through the non-zero values in a RealVector. I notice that the method RealVector.sparseIterator() can do this:

"Create a sparse iterator over the vector, which may omit some entries. The ommitted entries are either exact zeroes (for dense implementations) or are the entries which are not stored (for real sparse vectors). No guarantees are made about order of iteration."

However, the method returns

```
Iterator<RealVector.Entry>
```

object, where "Entry" is a protected class and therefore I cannot really use it outside of the RealVector class.

Have I misunderstood something? Is there anyway to iterate through the values in the RealVector object without converting them to double[], because the vector is very high dimensional and very sparse.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1329). It will most likely be fixed in the next release.